# How to make a function only available for the founder?

Tags: solidity

I have created a contract that allows a function issue, the code as followed;

```
function Issue(uint256 _value) public  {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += _value;            // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply += _value;                      // Updates totalSupply

 }
```

I want to edit that only the creator of the contract can Issue more token. I tried changing the public to internal, but after changing that, I cannot find the Issue function.

My questions is how do I edit this to make the issue only available to the founder?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the account that deployed the contract, and then you need to check `msg.sender` in your function to make sure it's the same account.

Here's an example from https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/26/checking-the-sender-in-a-smart-contract/:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract TipJar {

    address owner;    // current owner of the contract

    function TipJar() public {  // contract's constructor function
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
    }

    // unchanged code omitted
}
```

Comment: thank you buddy! I have figured out from your example! very helpful!

Comment: one more quick question, how to run    

 function TipJar() public {  // contract's constructor function
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

upon contract creation

Comment: The constructor is by definition run when you create the contract. It's the function with the same name as the contract.